# Shortening python code for shining LEDs in a sequence

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi2, led

I'm writing python 3.7 code to turn on LEDs one at a time for a certain period of time. 8 LEDs are wired to Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1 through a circuit. I would like users to be able to shine the LEDs in a sequence and for duration defined by them. I have defined 8 functions to shine each colour LED, only showing one here. This is my first coding experience, and I would like to know if there is a way not to manually code in all possible combinations of sequences like in the example below. I am only showing the beginning of the tree for one of the LEDs.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

q_colour = 'What LED colour would you like?'
q_duration = 'How many seconds should I turn it on for?'
q_another = 'Would you like to add another colour? yes/no'

def red_led(duration): 
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(18, HIGH)
    time.sleep(duration)
    GPIO.output(18, LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()

while True:
    colour = input(q_colour)

    if colour == 'quit':
        break
    if colour == 'red':
        another_colour = input('q_another')
    if another_colour == 'no':
        duration = input(q_duration)
        red_led(duration)
    else:
        colour = input(q_colour)
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would divide your code into a setup function where you set up all the pins.

```
int red = 18
int green = 19
int blue = 20

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(red, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(green, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(blue, GPIO.OUT)
```

Then you can generalize the function over arguments.

```
def turn_on_led(led):
    GPIO.output(led, HIGH)

def turn_off_led(led):
    GPIO.output(led, LOW)

# Initialize
setup()

# Example for a sequence should go into a function
turn_on_led(red)
turn_on_led(green)
time.sleep(5)
turn_off_led(red)
turn_off_led(green)
```